# Background Task in random channels Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my background task to send in different channels using `random.choice()`. When I turn the bot on, it will send in only one random channel and that channel only. Is there a way to send in a different channel each time it loops?

```
async def test_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channels = ['550528972226', '5149003563352', '514900351233', '5799132312340']
    channel = client.get_channel(random.choice(channels))
    while not client.is_closed:
        time = random.randint(1,5)+random.random()
        monies = random.randint(100,250)
        emojigrab = dollar
        emojimsg = await client.send_message(channel, emojigrab)
        await client.add_reaction(emojimsg, hand)
        pay = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji=hand, message=emojimsg, timeout=1800,
                                             check=lambda reaction, user: user != client.user)
        if pay:
            await client.delete_message(emojimsg)
            await client.send_message(channel, "{} collects {:,} dollars".format(pay.user.mention, monies))
            add_dollars(pay.user, monies)
            await asyncio.sleep(int(time))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `channel = client.get_channel(random.choice(channels))` is outside of your while loop, meaning that variable `channel` never changes. Move it to inside your while loop to change it every time a new message is going to be sent.

```
async def test_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channels = ['550528972226', '5149003563352', '514900351233', '5799132312340']
    while not client.is_closed:
        channel = client.get_channel(random.choice(channels))
        time = random.randint(1,5)+random.random()
        monies = random.randint(100,250)
        emojigrab = ''
        emojimsg = await client.send_message(channel, emojigrab)
        await client.add_reaction(emojimsg, "")
        pay = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji="", message=emojimsg, timeout=1800,
                                             check=lambda reaction, user: user != client.user)
        if pay:
            await client.delete_message(emojimsg)
            await client.send_message(channel, "{} secures the bag for ${:,}".format(pay.user.mention, monies))
            add_dollars(pay.user, monies)
            await asyncio.sleep(int(time))
```